# PDF Accessibility checker

Tags: html, pdf, accessibility

We are busy with improving our PDF files so that it's accessible for everyone, also for people with sight loss. At the moment we are using the following tool to verify if a PDF is accessible.

http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/downloading-pac.html

We are thinking that this is quite a good tool to verify if the PDF is accessible for people with sight loss, however we were wondering what other options we have to verify if a PDF is valid for people with sight loss.

The problem is that we have to solve the issues that are reported from the tool, like 'Path object not tagged', we were wondering how we should solve this in HTML as we are generating the PDF based on HTML.

Thanks

Comment: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." In particular asking whether such a tool is "the best" will trigger that tendency.

Comment: @mkl This seems that the question is more about how to solve the error reported by some tool, and what option exist to check for PDF accessibility without using that given tool. Although, this post should be edited to reflect that this post is not about recommending a tool.

Comment: @Adam Meanwhile indeed. The original question text appeared differently, though.

Comment: What tools are you using to generate tagged PDF? As far as I know, Acrobat Pro is your best bet.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe we have changed our approach and we use now Acrobat Pro to create a PDF that meet all accessibility requirements with a few dynamic fields that we will fill with iText in our Java code

Answer (score 0):

First off, no automated accessibility tool can substitute for a skilled person who understands the intent and practical implementation of WCAG / 508 standards.

For example, your "Path object not tagged" error is likely referring to a line segment or other vector shape that didn't correctly get tagged as an artifact.

If money is no object, then I recommend CommonLook tools, which are amazing, but very pricey. If you do this kind of work much, then these tools are absolutely worth the money.

Otherwise, I'd recommend using the accessibility checker in Acrobat Pro. Lots of government and enterprise organizations use nothing more than Acrobat Pro in their accessibility programs.